# Confusion with Python functions using an argument, keyword argument, *args, **kwargs

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

Given the below function and resulting calls to `print_stuff()`, can someone explain why there is unexpected behavior when calling the function without a keyword arg default but passing in a list to `*args`?

I'm aware of the "gotcha" involving mutable/immutable keyword defaults, but I don't see that being relevant here.

Can someone clarify why this occurs, or any syntax/invocation error?

```
def print_stuff(arg, kwarg=None, *args):
    print "arg: %s" % arg

    if kwarg:
        print "kwarg: %s" % kwarg

    if args:
        for a in args:
            print "printing {} from args".format(a)

    print "===end==="

args_list = range(1, 3)
kwargs_list = {str(a):a for a in args_list}

print_stuff('hi', kwarg='some_kwarg') # works as intended

print_stuff('hi', 'some_kwarg', *range(1, 3)) # also works as intended

print_stuff('hi', *range(1, 3)) # first element of list unexpectedly passed in to keyword argument, even using the * notation

print_stuff('hi', kwarg='some_kwarg', *range(1, 3)) # TypeError: print_stuff() got multiple values for keyword argument 'kwarg'
```

Comment: You don't have any keyword-**only** arguments, so whatever you pass in second is assigned to `kwarg`.

Comment: What's unexpected about the second value being passed in as the second argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from having a default value for `kwarg`, `print_stuff(arg, kwarg=None, *args)` is no different to `print_stuff(arg, kwarg, *args)` - if there is a second positional argument, it is passed as the `kwarg` parameter (any subsequent positional arguments end up in `args`).

Note that:

```
print_stuff('hi', *range(1, 3))
```

is evaluated as:

```
print_stuff('hi', 1, 2)
```

so the first argument goes to `arg`, the second goes to `kwarg` and the third to `args[0]`.

---

Then if we note that:

```
print_stuff('hi', kwarg='some_kwarg', *range(1, 3))
```

is equivalent to:

```
print_stuff('hi', *range(1, 3), kwarg='some_kwarg')
```

and therefore to:

```
print_stuff('hi', 1, 2, kwarg='some_kwarg')
```

you can perhaps see the problem - again `'hi'`, `1` and `2` go to `arg`, `kwarg` and `args[0]` respectively but then *another* value for `kwarg` turns up unexpectedly.

---

If you want all positional arguments to be "soaked up" *before* `kwarg` is considered, change the function definition to:

```
def print_stuff(arg, *args, **kwargs):
    print "arg: %s" % arg
    kwarg = kwargs.get('kwarg')
    if kwarg is not None:  # note explicit test - what if kwarg == 0?
        print "kwarg: %s" % kwarg

    for a in args:  # no need to test here - loop doesn't run if no args
        print "printing {} from args".format(a)

    print "===end==="
```

In use:

```
>>> print_stuff('hi', *range(1, 3))
arg: hi
printing 1 from args
printing 2 from args
===end===
>>> print_stuff('hi', *range(1, 3), kwarg='some_kwarg')
arg: hi
kwarg: some_kwarg
printing 1 from args
printing 2 from args
===end===
```

Note that in 3.x you can have [*keyword-only arguments*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/), i.e. the following is an alternative:

```
def print_stuff(arg, *args, kwarg=None):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, this is chosen as it provides an explanation + solution.

Answer (score 1):

`kwarg` is not a keyword-only argument; it's just a positional argument that has a default. Your call

```
print_stuff('hi', *range(1,3))
```

is exactly the same as

```
print_stuff('hi', 1, 2)
```

which assigns the first two arguments to the first two named parameters, and the remaining (i.e., the third) is placed in the `*args` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to think of it is this:

When an argument is passed to a function, it gets added to a positional argument "queue" of sorts. Python will ignore keyword arguments and prioritize non-keyword arguments when assigning to this queue. All keyword arguments are assigned *last* in function calls. You can imagine this as Python "shifting around the order" of your arguments because its eager to fill positions first. So with a call like:

`print_stuff('hi', kwarg='some_kwarg', *range(1,3))`

Python will basically transform it into:

`print_stuff('hi', 1, 2, kwarg='some_kwarg')`

and then will get angry because you assign to kwarg twice.

***Note that this is not necessarily what *actually* happens, but it's a good way of thinking about it because you will be able to handle mistakes and can also explain why in a call like:

`print_stuff('hi', *range(1,3))`

the 1 gets passed to the 2nd positional argument kwarg, and the 2 gets passed to the 3rd argument args.

Comment: thanks, it is useful to think of it as shifting around the argument queue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply i am writing a function to show how `*args` and `**kwargs` works

```
def test_function(normal_arg, *arg, **kwargs):
    print(locals())
    return

test_function("normal_arg-value", 
    "*arg1-value", "*arg2-value",
    karg1="karg1-value", karg2="karg2-value")

#output
{'arg1': 'arg1-value', 'arg': ('*arg1-value', '*arg2-value'), 'kwargs': {'karg2': 'karg2-value', 'karg1': 'karg1-value'}}
```

Hope this helps.

**How unlimited of arguments can pass to a function**

```
def test(*lis):
    print locals()

test(1,2,3)

#output
{'lis': (1, 2, 3)}
```

**How unlimited named arguments can pass to a function**

```
def test(**dicts):
    print locals()

test(arg1="value1", arg2="value2")

#output
{'dicts': {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'}}
```

**How a dictionary pass to a function as argument**

```
def test(**dicts):
    print locals()

test(**{"arg1":"value1", "arg2": "value2"})

#output
{'dicts': {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'}}
```

Hope this helps you